# Current limiter doesn't work

Tags: mosfet, current-source, current-limiting

I've built simple current source with current limiter. Regulated part of the circuit is supplied by 10V from Lab Power Supply in which I set also current limit to some value. 
Idea is that U1 pushes current through M1, so that Power Supply reaches its current limit and is forced to lower the voltage - thus reaching voltage set on R2 potentiometer. In addition to that, U2 is preventing whole circuit to draw too much current - it has priority over U1.

it works fine. In reality, however, it works for small currents, but as soon as I increase maximum current using potentiometer R7, difference between voltage in point A and point B start to increase. So for current limited to 20mA I get 20mV difference. For current limited to 70mA I get 40mV difference.

Anyone got idea why difference is increasing with current? How can I fix this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbEvSA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This seems overly complex. You should be able to do it with 1 opamp, 1 sense/current limiting resistor, 1 pot and 1 transistor, like e.g. https://www.instructables.com/id/Constant-Current-Source-with-Operational-Amplifier/

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Where is the load?  A current source already limits the current, so a limiter is redundant. A current limiter would make more sense when used with a constant voltage source.

Comment: @Mattman944 By setting current limit on Lab Power Supply, I'm trying to simulate behaviour of solar panel. Whole idea is to keep solar panel's output on constant voltage, meaning when voltage is too high - increase current, and vice versa. But in addition to that, I would like to have overcurrent protection